# Docker MySQL can't connect to socket

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, nginx, docker, passenger

I'm learning Docker and I've a problem trying to connect a Rails app on the `passenger-full` container and a `mysql` container. Both are linked in a compose file

```
app:
  build: ./rails
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - database
  volumes:
    - ./rails:/home/app/webapp
database:
  image: mysql
  environment:
    - MYSQL_DATABASE="dockertest"
    - MYSQL_USER="dockertest"
    - MYSQL_PASSWORD="dockertest"
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD="root"
```

So I added the `apt-get install` at the top of my Dockerfile like this

```
FROM phusion/passenger-full
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev mysql-client -y

# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root

# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]

RUN rm -f /etc/service/nginx/down
RUN rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
ADD webapp.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf

RUN mkdir /home/app/webapp
WORKDIR /home/app/webapp
ADD . /home/app/webapp
RUN cd /home/app/webapp && bundle install
RUN touch /home/app/webapp/tmp/restart.txt

# Clean up APT when done.
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
```

Also this is my `database.yml` in the Rails app.

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dockertest
  host: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MYSQL_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT'] %>
  username: dockertest
  password: dockertest

development:
  <<: *default

production: 
  <<: *default
```

The problem is that I cant stop receiving the error

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

The webconf file is

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;
    root /home/app/webapp/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_user app;
    passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby2.2;
}
```

Is that the right way to do this? As you can see I'm pretty new to docker.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem here is with the `links` directive in your `docker-compose.yml` file.  You have:

```
links:
  - database
```

That's basically saying that the link `name:alias` is `database:database`, according to the `docker-compose.yml` [reference](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/compose/yml/#links).

Also, if you read the [linking container docs](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/userguide/dockerlinks/) you can see that the environments exported to the source container are of the format `ALIAS_XXX` for example `ALIAS_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT`. So in essence in your `database.yml` what you want to do is something like this:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dockertest
  host: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT_3306_TCP_ADDR'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['DATABASE_PORT_3306_TCP_PORT'] %>
  username: dockertest
  password: dockertest

development:
  <<: *default

production: 
  <<: *default
```

If you want to use the `MYSQL` alias your links would have to look something like this in your `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
links:
  - database:mysql
```

The error:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

is basically coming from your Rails app not being to see what's in your database.yml and defaulting to a local `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` connection.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your help, especially for the level of detail and good explanation. Now the `docker-compose run app rake db:migrate` runs successfully, which means that the `rake` program with `production` and `development` environments is able to reach the database container. But from the passenger rails app I'm still getting the `Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)` error. I added the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/webapp.conf` file for more details, if you have time to take a look

Comment: Well, I change `mysql:latest -> mysql:5.5` and `passenger-full -> passenger-ruby21` and everything worked